# Why is my google places autocomplete not responding well on mobile?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my website www.planeandtrain.com I am using google places autocomplete for autocomplete suggestions. This is working well on a normal PC.

However on a mobile device there occurs a problem when the user makes a spelling mistake and presses the backbutton to delete some letters and then starts writing again. Sometimes the typed letters don't show up in the form, or un-expected letters show up (in addition, or instead of what has been typed).

What could be that the autocomplete places is not responding well on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the google autocomplete suggestions, as this problem also occurs with the original example on the google page. I made a bug report to google.